# AWS IAM access exception with AWS CodePipeline when integrating with BitBucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to build a Pipeline for our CICD process using AWS CodePipeline. I click on "Create Pipeline", provide a name and use the defaults for the first panel. On the next panel, on selecting "BitBucket(beta)" as the source provider, I get the following access exception:

**AccessDeniedException:**
User: arn:aws:iam::280945876345:user/Roger is not authorized to perform: codestar-connections:ListConnections on resource: arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-west-2:280945876345:*

I went through the documentation and provided full access to CodePipeline, CodeDeploy, CodeStar, CodeBuildAdmin, CloudFormation, AmazonS3, AmazonECS, AWSCodeCommit to the IAM user. I dont find any policies related to codestar-connections:* that I could add. I understand the CodePipeline-BitBucket integration is in Beta phase, but just wanted to check if anyone else had encountered this issue and resolved it.

Comment: You have to add `codestar-connections:*` to the Roger role.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I add codestar-connections:* to the user Roger ? I dont find a policy with that name. I tried creating a policy as shown below:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action" : "codestar-connections:*",
            "Resource" : "*"
     }]
}
I get a message "This policy does not grant any permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition", which I believe means that service is not available.

Comment: One way one of doing this is: Go to IAM->Roles->Roger role. Add inline policy directly to the role. You have to construct the policy yourself. Console should guide you.

Comment: I went ahead and added the codestar-connections* policy to the user and ignored the message that the service is not available. It works now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. I will add an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Comment: @gsa you should mark the answer from Marcin as correct answer for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, the problem was due to missing permissions to `codestar-connections`.

The solution was to create an inline policy in the role in question with permissions to `codestar-connections:*`.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me updating the User permissions by performing the following steps:

1. Visit the page that lists all of your users in IAM via this link: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home?#/users
2. Select the user to whom we need to give permission
3. Click on `+ Add inline policy` button on the left
4. Click `Choose a service` in front of `Service` field
5. Type in the search bar `CodeStar Connections` and click on it in the search results
6. I selected `All CodeStar Connections actions (codestar-connections:*)` checkbox whereas you can select any of the access level as per your requirements.
7. This sometimes creates warnings and ask you to add `ARN` from the `Resources` field. In that case, click on `Add ARN` and fill up the fields.
8. Click on `Review Policy` at the bottom to proceed with adding this policy to the user.

Another option is to update permissions of the entire [user group](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home#/groups)

Answer (score 0):

Both Marcin and Adil answers worked for me, but then when trying to deploy received this error "user is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole".

Then I found this [link](https://github.com/ysugimoto/aws-lambda-image/issues/153) that helped me with the final policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codestar-connections:GetIndividualAccessToken",
                "codestar-connections:CreateConnection",
                "codestar-connections:ListInstallationTargets",
                "codestar-connections:StartOAuthHandshake",
                "codestar-connections:GetInstallationUrl",
                "codestar-connections:ListHosts",
                "codestar-connections:StartAppRegistrationHandshake",
                "codestar-connections:RegisterAppCode",
                "codestar-connections:ListConnections",
                "codestar-connections:CreateHost"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codestar-connections:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codestar-connections:*:474678791249:connection/*",
                "arn:aws:codestar-connections:*:474678791249:host/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:CreatePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Pasting this into the JSON editor instead of the Visual editor creates the policy using the previous JSON.